# Which hook to use to reorder multi-value field values before saving content

Tags: hooks, entities

I have a multi-value field added to my content type. It is actually a field collection.

The users can add unlimited items to this field, and rearrange the items using Drupal's drag-and-drop utility.

However, I want to add some custom logic to the arrangement of field values according to the content.

Which hook should I use, to modify the arrangement of field values before the node saved into the database.

For example, I have the following structure:

```
My Content Type
|
|-- Field Collection Field // unlimited values
    |
    |-- Name // Text field
    |-- Surname // Text field
    |-- Company // Select list
```

Let's say a user created a content with the following values:

- John - Doe - ACME
- Jane - Doe - Ace
- Bob - X - ACME
- Fred - Something - Ace

I want to sort them with a custom logic in a hook, so that they are arranged like that:

- Bob - X - ACME
- John - Doe - ACME
- Fred - Something - Ace
- Jane - Doe - Ace

My question is NOT how to write the logic, BUT which hook to use to modify the arrangements so that I can put my function into it.

Comment: Just as a suggestion, would it make any sense to leave the reordering to display time (eg. via a custom formatter or a [`hook_field_attach_view_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_attach_view_alter/7)? This could prove useful if you ever need to support multiple sort methods.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think that I would ever need any other sort method. The reason why I want to do it before saving, is that the function called only once and all is good. If I implement it on display time, that means the function will be called every time the node is viewed, and it would impact the performance.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you [hook_node_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) to modify node edit form submitted values before saving it into DB.

Comment: I think you could also use [`hook_field_attach_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_attach_presave/7) if you wanted to be entity type agnostic.

Comment: @Andy this hook seems very interesting. I'll definitely try that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Attach a custom validate handler for the **element** and make sure it will be called first. Then in your validate function you can change the field weight in `$form_state`.

Comment: This would only work if the node is created using the form. It won't work if the nodes are created programmatically, for example using feeds.

Comment: I have done something similar to this sometime back. If you are going to use hook_node_presage then changing the weight won't work, you might have to rearrange the array itself.

Comment: Thanks, I am planning to use [`usort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and rearrange the array according to my custom logic.

Comment: I am not sure whether it will work, let me know of you make it work